# getting error 404 while passing an array through ajax to the controller

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

i have a loop like this in my view that generates the list of student`s names

```
<Table id="your_table">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>grade</th>
    <th>remove</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (string item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td id="td_name" style="border-left: thin">@item</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="txtGrade_@item" onclick="" style="width: 40px;border-left: thin" /></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" id="chkStudent_@item" value="@item" /></td>
        </tr>

    }
</tbody>
```

i use the script below to get the text for the first cell of each row :

```
$('#btnDone')
          .click(function() {
        //get studentslist
        function getFirstCellTextList(tableElement) {
            if (tableElement instanceof jQuery) {
                // Create an array
                var textList = [];
                // Iterate over each table row
                tableElement.find('tbody tr').each(function () {
                    // Get the first cells's text and push it inside the array
                    var row = $(this);
                    if (row.children('td').length > 0) {
                        textList.push(row.children('td').eq(0).text());
                    }
                });
                return textList;
            }
            return null;
        }
        // Get the array
        var lststudents = getFirstCellTextList($('#your_table'));
        var result = [];
        $(lststudents).each(function(index, item) {
            result.push(item);
        });

       alert(result);
       $.ajax('/TeacherPages/GetGrades/' + result).done(function () {
           alert("done");
       });
    });
```

the problem is. when i want to send the created array to the controller i get error 404. there is something wrong with this array. because when i manually add values to the array the ajax works without any problems

this is my action:

```
[AttributeRouting.Web.Mvc.GET("/TeacherPages/GetGrades/{result}")]
    public PartialViewResult GetGrades(string[] result)
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: don't hardcode url, do like: `$.ajax('@Url.Action("GetGrades","TeacherPages")'` and show your action how it looks like?

Comment: You cannot just append a javascript array to a url - you url would need to look like `/TeacherPages/GetGrades?name=ABC&name=DEF&name=etc` if you method had a parameter `IEnumerable<string> name. What does you array look like?

Comment: its like : name1.lastname1, name2.lastname2

Comment: Why are the dots in there? That's going to cause issues with binding. Can you edit the question to show the value of `result`

Comment: dots are there so i can split them after i get the value in my action

Comment: The solution is simple (and I will add an answer later). But _so i can split them_ makes no sense - split them for what? You can just pass back the correct model in the first place. What are you doing with the data you receive in the `result` parameter?

Comment: in the data base user name and user last name are separated into two different columns i had to do something like this to join them together so the user can see student`s full name and separate them each time i receive the data in my actions. using empty space for splitting is also a no go because there are lots of records are there that contains white spaces by users who accidentally press space after they wrote their names

Comment: That is not the right way to go about it - your can just do something like `@string.Format("{0} {1}" item.FirstName, item.LastName)` in the view. But why would you send all that back to the controller again (its not editable) - all you should be sending back is the ID of the item. And if you did want to do that, then you would send back a collection of the model.

Comment: to get to this view the data has to pass through  several other actions some even in different controllers its easier this way considering the data base architecture. the most important thing is. even if i want to send like 10 IDs that are stored in an array it still cant reach the action. because of  error 404

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot just append a javascript array to your url. It just converts the values in the array to a comma separated string whereas you need to generate a url which is

```
/TeacherPages/GetGrades?result=someValue&result=anotherValue&result=etc...
```

Change your script to

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetGrades", "TeacherPages")', // don't hardcode your url's
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true,
    data: { result: result },
    success: function (response) {
        ....
    }
});
```

As a side note, your `getFirstCellTextList()` function is returning the array you want and its pointless to create another identical array from it. You just need

```
var result = getFirstCellTextList($('#your_table'));
```

Comment: thank you. that did it. but is odd. i tried to send information like this to actions in this project in several different occasions with no errors.